# Seeking Advice on Handling Systematic Missingness Due to Conditional Logic in Dataset for Binary Outcome Analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, missing-data

I am tackling a complex multivariate analysis project with a binary outcome variable. My dataset's unique challenge arises from structured missingness due to conditional logic responses, significantly complicating the preprocessing stage. I am reaching out for insights on the best practices to manage this situation, keeping in mind the logical relationships between certain variables and the binary nature of the outcome variable.

Data Overview: The dataset comprises around 15 independent variables spanning various domains, including sexual behavior, socioeconomic status, and health indicators. The dependent variable categorizes a specific health outcome into two states.
Conditional Logic and Missingness:
One primary response based on participants' activity dictates whether subsequent related questions are applicable, leading to a large volume of systematically missing data across several variables for a subset of respondents.
The reporting of partner numbers (both steady and casual) further introduces conditional missingness, affecting additional related variables based on the count being zero.
Challenge: Given the structured absence of data and its potential to skew the analysis, I'm exploring effective data preparation strategies that can robustly handle this complexity, particularly considering the binary outcome. The primary concern is how to manage the missingness without compromising the analysis's integrity or introducing significant bias.
I am keen on understanding whether multiple imputation stands out as the most suitable approach for my scenario or if alternative strategies might better accommodate the type of systematic missingness present in my dataset.
I would really appreciate any advice you could offer on appropriate models.

Thank you in advance!